# Stuck With MFC Propertysheet

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2005, propertysheet

I am trying to do a property sheet application in MFC.
I added the dialogues for each tab and all working fine.
But my actual problem is that when I placed a button on one of the tab, the program control actually not reaching there. This is what I have done.

1. Added a new dialog--> Created its **class** referring from **CPropertyPage** class
2. Added a button and textbox in **gender** tab and tried the below code:

   void Gender::OnBnClickedBUTTON()
   {
       SetDlgItemInt(TEXTBOX_ID,1)
   }

I'm expecting the **textbox** to be printed with integer **1**. But nothing happens.
Should I add something else?
I am actually stuck with the control flow of the program. please help.

Comment: If the textbox is an edit control it should update automatically, but if it's a static control you may need to invalidate it after setting the new value. Microsoft assume static controls will be static, i.e. unchanging.

Comment: Its an _edit control_ I didnot added any variables for it yet. trying to do with SetDlgItemInt().

Comment: Did you use the wizard to add the OnBnClicked function? If not then you'll be missing the required entry in the message map.

Comment: Yes I used the wizard and Message map looks like: <br/> BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(Gender, CPropertyPage)
 ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &Gender::OnBnClickedButton1)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

Comment: There's your problem then. In the message map, the function should be called &Gender::OnBnClickedBUTTON, not OnBnClickedButton1.